# Blender freezing and high cpu usage on "decent" rig

Tags: texturing

When I enter texture view mode I get unbelieveable high CPU usage ( 50-100% ) and blender freezes for about 10sec then unfreezes then again freeze, sometimes it stops working altogether.

I've tried every possible option inside blender and outside, nothing seems to work.

Also, memory goes from like 70mb to 1500mb and freezes.

GPU : AMD RX480 4gb
CPU : i3 6100
RAM : 16gb

Comment: Will be good know how complex is your scene, maybe try it on different PC. But I thing, this is only about low CPU performance. Sorry buddy, but you can't wait miracles with this office CPU. Texture mod and mesh bended by bones is quite slow even on powerful machines. You can try opensubdiv and different setting in User preferences - system,but I don't thing this help you

Comment: I have about 400 tris. It doesnt matter how complex is my scene, I don't lag in object or edit more, only in texture mode... And this problem only started to occur about 2 weeks ago. I'm using blender for about 3-4 years and didn't had that problem ever.

Comment: Since you mention that it didn't happen before, what changed in your computer? Did you make an update on the OS? Have you tried updating (or downgrading) the drivers for your graphics card? Do you have any other apps open at the same time? Are you using the same version of blender?

Comment: The thing I upgraded was new 8gb of ram. So I now have 2x8, and around that time blender started lagging. I also tried other version of blender 2.77 and 2.78 it's still the same, idk  whats going on.